# C# Treat part of string as var

Tags: c#, string, replace

I've got a string (from an external text file) which contains words corresponding to existing variables. Is there any way to replace the words with the contents of the variables?
Maybe by enclosing the words with {}?

For example, in psudeo code, this:

```
string var1 = "Works";
string from_text = "It {var1}!";
```

Would result in "It Works!"

Edit: I have no idea what variables are used in the external text file. Could be var1 like in the example, could as well be var24123 or int2312. So, would have to be dynamic :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of C# 6.0, this is actually possible. It is called [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx). Most examples work with a format string which is known at compile time:

```
string from_text = $"It {var1}!";
```

It is however also possible to make a dynamic string with [`FormattableString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formattablestring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var formattableString = new FormattableString() {
    Format = "It {var1}!",
    Args = new object[] { var1 }
});
string from_text = formattableString.ToString();
```

Comment: String interpolation did exactly what I wanted :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could use: `string from_text = string.Format("It {0}!", var1);`

Answer (score 1):

In C# 6 you might be able to use the new [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn986596.aspx) operator:

```
string var1 = "Works";
string from_text = "It {var1}!";
string replaced = from_text.Replace("{" + nameof(var1) + "}", var1);
```

However I'm not sure how very useful this is.

Answer (score 1):

In pre-C# 6: `string from_text = string.Format("It {0}!", var1);`
In C# 6: `string from_text = $"It {var1}!";`